# Can I view enemy resistances without playing in Combat Wait mode?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I played through the tutorial and it said that you can view enemy resistances by putting combat into wait mode. I don't like playing in wait mode most of the time. Is there anyway to view resistances other than going in wait mode, or a quicker way to switch between wait and active modes without going to the options menu?

Answer (score 15):

If you get the Analyze skill (6 AP, Ignis ability) on the Ascension Grid, you will automatically scan most enemies at the start of battle to see the HP and resistances (essentially Libra) of the enemy that you are locked on to.

[image: Teamwork]

[image: Analyze]

Comment: Is there any way to check it after the scanning has occurred? I ask because after about 20 hours sometimes I don't seem to get any data for an enemy. I just use my memory, but certain members of this site are very old and can't even remember how old they are.

Comment: Once Ignis has analyzed an enemy, it should show a grey icon on the left side of the enemy's hp bar, hold R1 to see the resistances and hp on the top left of the screen.