# Is there any point in upgrading the 'Wait mode' tree when using Active Mode?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

FFXV has two types of combat, toggleable in the options:

- Wait mode, which pauses combat when you're not moving
- Active mode, which never pauses combat

There is an entire skill-tree labeled "wait mode".  Is there any point in upgrading this tree if you're playing in Active Mode?

Comment: Since I am still early on in the game reading over the skill descriptions all of the skills mention while in wait mode besides Elementalist. I would post this as an answer but I am unsure if Elementalist is only active in wait mode.

Comment: IIRC the only way to inspect an enemy's resistances is to be in Wait mode, so even if you mostly play in Active combat mode, there are times when you'll want to switch.

Comment: @MattCasto According to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292826/can-i-view-enemy-resistances-without-playing-in-combat-wait-mode that's not true

Comment: Ignis can analyze an enemy (I believe you need to unlock that in the ascension tree, it was one of my first upgrades). Press  (hold i think) your lock on button to see the weaknesses of the enemy. These will only be visible after Ignis identified them.

Comment: @MattCasto Pressing R1 on PS4 and RB on XBOX uses Libra in Active Mode, but it's easier to process and understand in Wait Mode than Active Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Wait Mode skill tree appeals to a Tactician whereas Active Mode appeals to a Strategist and the benefit of spending AP in WAIT MODE is great should you find more comfort in a tactical role.

The AP in wait mode is designed to give players the same scope of information afforded in Active Mode, standing still.

For example, on PS4 Libra is activated with R1 (RB in XBOX), but you have to select the target and you typically only have a brief moment you can check Libra during combat. In WAIT MODE, you can be more precise in your actions because you have time to plan while you do not move.

As long as you don't plan on playing in Wait Mode, you're fine without using AP in the skills. If you do plan on it at some point however, Wait Mode is weakened unless you use the AP. Fortunately, the AP required is minimal compared to other skill trees.